# Problem with method called from two observer

Tags: magento-1.8

I have an action in order list called "SEND"(shipment) which runs smoothly and there modelA_observer salesOrderShipmentSaveBefore observer with the method and it works perfect.

I create a new action called "SEND_CUSTOM" which one observer called _modelB_observer imlementa also has a method called salesOrderShipmentSaveBefore.

The problem is that when I click on "SEND_CUSTOM" called me the two functions are executed and both codes (A and B). I disabled the observer _modelA_observer from _modelB_observer and achieve that when you click on "SEND_CUSTOM" would be executed only _modelB_observer code (fine). BUT,  when I click on the action "SEND" _modelA_observer not the code is executed and the log according to the code runs twice _modelB_observer.

I need that when the administrator click "SEND" _modelA_observer only the code is executed, and when you click on "SEND_CUSTOM" the code is executed only _modelB_observer. It is possible??

Thanks. (Magento 1.8)